# Can a non-null assertion be combined with a ternary?

Tags: angular, typescript, operators

Let's suppose that I want to grab an 'id' parameter from my route in an Angular application using TypeScript.

I could do something like this: `this!.route!.snapshot!.parent!.paramMap.get('id')`

However, if my assertion is wrong and part of the chain returns `null`, then this will throw an exception at runtime.

So would doing something like this ever make sense?
`this!.route!.snapshot!.parent!.paramMap.get('id') ? this!.route!.snapshot!.parent!.paramMap.get('id') : '-1'`

Or would it always return the first operand (and fail, if null)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget that the TS will be compiled to JS, and non-null assertions are non-existant in JS.

So you have two solutions :

- test each step

  ```
  x = this && this.route && this.route.snapshot && ... || '-1'
  ```
- Use a try catch block

  ```
  try {
    x = this.route.snapshot.parent.paramMap.get('id');
  } catch(error) {
    x = '-1';
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for this. So I take it that `this!.route!.snapshot!.parent!.paramMap.get('id') ? this!.route!.snapshot!.parent!.paramMap.get('id') : '-1'` isn't a useful expression, then?

Comment: As far as I know, this will not change a thing in JS, this is only for the type checker (to avoid linting errors) in case you define a variable as null OR (like `number | null`)

Comment: I think I understand what you mean now. Basically, that expression would transpile to `this.route.snapshot.parent.paramMap.get('id') ? this.route.snapshot.parent.paramMap.get('id') : '-1'` (i.e. - no `!`s) in javascript, right?

In other words, the resulting *javascript* expression would be useful in that it would return `-1` if `null`; but the transpilation would render the non-null assertions pointless.

Comment: Almost, if you ever encounter an error in JS, it will output an error instead of returning a value. That's where the try catch block comes in handy. But either way, the non null assertion will be inexistant in JS.